# in React, how to call a function living in another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-component

in my react's `App.js`'s `return` i am currently calling `this.searchVenues()` in a way that works but is messy and i know there is a better way. The `searchVenues()` function lives in `App.js` and I have buttons that need to be in their own component, then just `<ButtonComponent/>` instead of:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="App container-fluid">
        <Navbar/>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-xs-3">
          <button onClick ={() => this.searchVenues("yoga+coffee", "5")}>5</button>
            <button onClick ={() => this.searchVenues("yoga+coffee", "10")}>10</button>
            <button onClick ={() => this.searchVenues("yoga+coffee", "15")}>15</button>
            <SideBar {...this.state} handleListItemClick={this.handleListItemClick}/>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-9 full-height">
            <Map {...this.state}
            handleMarkerClick={this.handleMarkerClick}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

but when i do `this.searchVenues("yoga+coffee", "5")` does not work, understandably so. What's the best or a better way to make it work? How do i access the function from another file ( component )?

Comment: Pull the function out into a service and import the service where you need it

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to declare your searchVenues func in App.js component like this:

```
searchVenues = (arg1, arg2) => {here is the body of your function}
```

... and pass it down to the ButtonComponent using props:

```
<ButtonComponent searchVenues={this.searchVenues}
```

Once you are in your stateless ButtonComponent, you can create a new function inside it if you want to avoid anonymous functions in your render ([you can read on it here](https://medium.com/@machnicki/handle-events-in-react-with-arrow-functions-ede88184bbb))

```
const searchVenues = (arg1, arg2) => { 
    return event => {props.searchVenues(arg1, arg2);}
}
```

... and add it to the onClick event:

```
<button onClick ={searchVenues('coffee+yoga', props.value)}>{props.value}</button>
```

Comment: You probably want to wrap `props.value` in curly brackets :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want your buttons to live in another component, but receive handlers from another component, you can pass them down through props.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import MyButton from './MyButton'

export default class App extends Component {

    buttonClickHandler= () => {
        alert('I have been clicked!')
    }

    render = () => (
        <MyButton onClickHandler={this.buttonClickHandler} />
    )
}
```

And here is the MyButton component file:

```
import React from 'react'

const MyButton = (props) => (
    <button onClick={props.onClickHandler}>Click Me for an Alert!</button>
)

export default MyButton
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either have `searchVenues` defined in your `ButtonComponent` or pass it to `ButtonComponent` as a prop. Then in your `ButtonComponent` render function you would do the same thing:

`<button onClick ={() => this.searchVenues("yoga+coffee", "15")}>15</button>`

or if it is passed as a prop

`<button onClick ={() => this.props.searchVenues("yoga+coffee", "15")}>15</button>`

I will also add that @Bryan is absolutely right about services. Lets say for instance you have a table in a database called **Product**. Well, you don't want to implement `getAllProducts()` in every component that needs a list of products. Instead, you would create a class called **ProductService** where `getAllProducts()` would be defined. Then, for any component that needs a list of products, you would import the **ProductService** class and call `ProductService.getAllProducts()`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute methods from any component, and the result of those methods will change the global state of the app, you might benefit from using `actions`.
Whether you're using flux or redux architecture, actions can be triggered from any part of the app, and perform changes in the global state, this changes will be reflected on any component that is listening to this state.

https://reactjs.org/blog/2014/07/30/flux-actions-and-the-dispatcher.html
https://redux.js.org/basics/actions